# why is there a sub-domain existing which I didn't create?

Tags: subdomain

I resigstered a new domain visitsoonvalley.com but now I can see that there is a sub-domain support.visitsoonvalley.com which I didn't create and I can't find in the cpanel too. This page is showing ads and the first advertisement is of the company that I registered my domain with. Is it possible that they created this sub domain? Are they allowed to do this without notifying me?

UPDATE: I just checked going to help.visitsoonvalley.com and same result. Why are these sub domains existing?!

Comment: I fail to see how this question even remotely relates to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot register subdomains. You cannot really create them. You can only use them.

Most likely there is a "wildcard DNS resolution" for your domain. That would be something your provider has done and it actually does make some sense, since most people want that. Why don't you simply ask them? They will probably remove it from your DNS settings if you ask them.

A "wildcard DNS resolution" means that *all* DNS resolution requests to hostnames within your domain are resolved to the same IP address, without any specific rule existing. So it is a kind of "fallback".

Why there are ads shown in your page is nothing we can say. Might be some default content your provider puts in as a placeholder until you create content. Or they simply created a DNS resolution as a palceholder until you name an IP address the domain should be resolved to. Again: why don't you ask your provider? You pay them for their service, so usually that means the have to give support...

Certainly that is not exactly a "nice" behavior if that really is not mentioned anywhere in their policy. But on the other hand it does no harm and is only temporary...